# irradiance of blue LED light

Tags: led, power-electronics, led-strip

[image]i have small rectangular box with blue led strip 450 nm placed on top of the box. what device should i use in order to measure its power density or the irradiance of my blue LED?

Comment: I would recommend a photodiode and get it calibrated if you want accuracy.

Comment: okay andy , i will try to research about photodiodes. thanks

Comment: Buy an old fashioned photographic light meter with an incident light/integrating dome.  It might not give you absolute units you can compare with a standard as it is made for typically white light but it should give you pretty repeatable results if you want to compare tests or devices.

Answer (score 2):

- First specify WHY you want to measure this.
- Second define exactly what you want to measure along with resolution and accuracy for each wavelength.

  e.g.  Is it relative to the Eye or to spectral energy. 
      [**These are not the same thing.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminance)

If you wish to measure the Eye response level then use an Ambient Light sensor which is a PD with Eye spectrum Matching optical filter.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/AMS302/255-2655-ND/2125641

Then consider the ambient light that needs to blocked like a camera with a lens, recessed aperture, focal length and calibrate with a precision distance understanding the sensitivity to positional errors.

[image] 
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need an optical power meter or optical spectrometer.

**Power**

I have a newport power meter with which I measure a power of a laser source, as it has a very narrow band. You could try using it to *estimate* the power of your LED. Depending on LED, it may have a wide bandwidth centered at 450nm, so the optical spectrometer would be more appropriate to measure the light intensity as the function of the wavelength, since the total power should be integrated over the range of frequencies.

[image]

**Radiation**

This information should be provided by the manufacturer of the LED, since it depends on the optical/geometrical properties of the beam (divergence, power concentration vs angle, etc.).

[image]

**Irradiance**

This says how much radiation the illuminated surface gets. Thus, knowing the information from Radiant power distribution you can estimate how much power your surface is exposed to.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49867/discussion-on-answer-by-naz-irradiance-of-blue-led-light).